# SQL Server getting value from a dynamic sql procedure into a table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a temp table variable inside a sql procedure which I update using a dynamic sql like this

```
insert into @ResultSetTable exec(@query)
```

this works fine ,I need to update the table inside the same stored procedure with another value from another dynamic sql which returns one scalar value but it doesn't update and always has 0 for that column, I checked running the dynamic sql separately it returns values correctly only its not getting updated

```
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@finalvalue int out', @finalvalue output

update @ResultSetTable set finalvalue = @finalvalue where 
          [ID]=@ID
```

can someone help out

Comment: `@finalvalue` can only hold one value, so your update with no where clause would set the entire `@ResultSetTable.finalvalue` column to that one value. Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: I think you are right I should include a where clause I thought initially this is called inside a cursor loop but as u said the final value got from this dynamic sql will update all previous rows.

Comment: Still the table contains only 0 for the updated col

Comment: @TimLehner the query returns a scalar value should I declare it as out inside the procedure will it only then get the value into finalvalue

Comment: So I couldn't figure this out so added one more table just for that scalar value and stored the result from the stored proc into this table ,later updated the first table with this row :-( I know its not efficient but workd